# R leaflet display the polygon label by default

Tags: html, r, leaflet

I am new to the leaflet package. 
I am trying to draw two types of polygons and let the user select them and see the borders. These polygons have labels and I want to display them by default. At the moment the labels are displayed only on mouse hover. 
Basically what I want is to let the user search for the polygon label on the map. 
Given below is my code.

```
shp <- readOGR(dsn = 'shapes'
               ,layer = 'SAB')

postcode <- readOGR(dsn = 'shapes'
               ,layer = 'Postcode')

CRS_WGS84 <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'

t_shp <- spTransform(shp, CRS(CRS_WGS84))

sab_shp <- raster::aggregate(t_shp, by='SMALL_AREA')


dat <- data.table(shp@data)

sabLabels <- sprintf('<strong>SAB: %s', t_shp$SMALL_AREA) %>% lapply(HTML)

postcode <- readOGR(dsn = 'shapes'
                    ,layer = 'Postcode')

CRS_WGS84 <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'

t_shp2 <- spTransform(postcode, CRS(CRS_WGS84))

postcode_shp <- raster::aggregate(t_shp2, by='RoutingKey')


dat2 <- data.table(postcode@data)

postcodeLabels <- sprintf('<strong>SAB: %s', t_shp2$RoutingKey) %>% lapply(HTML)


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  #using default does not allow html export to include the underlying
  #OSM layer
  addProviderTiles('OpenStreetMap.Mapnik') %>%
  addPolygons( data = t_shp
               ,stroke = T
               ,fillColor = 'grey'
               ,fillOpacity = 0.2
               ,color = 'blue'
               ,weight = 0.5
               ,label = sabLabels
               ,group = 'SABS'
               ,highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "blue", weight = 7,
                                                    bringToFront = TRUE)
               #,labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, textOnly = TRUE, opacity = 0.5 , textsize='15px')

  ) %>%

  addPolygons( data = t_shp2
               ,stroke = T
               ,fillOpacity = 0
               ,color = 'black'
               ,weight = 1.5
               ,label = postcodeLabels
               ,group = 'PostCodes'
  ) %>%
addLayersControl(
  overlayGroups = c(
    'SABS'
    ,'PostCodes'

  )
  ,options = layersControlOptions((collapsed = F))
)
```

Comment: Could you share your `shapes`  file ?

Comment: how do i share a file in here?

Comment: See this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources